# Is it semantic HTML to put my webpage reviews inside <blockquote>?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, blockquote

I have a presentation-like carousel slider containing customer reviews concerning my website and its services. Semantics speaking, is it correct to have each review inside a blockquote?

Example:

```
<figure class="review-single">
 <blockquote>Review content</blockquote>
 <figcaption>Said by John Doe</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Interesting take on the `<figure>` (Don't forget to close it) and `<figcaption>` as the signature. The `<blockquote>` is spot on and I cannot really object to the figset although it's unorthodox but in context of it being a slide in a presentation I guess it's ok. Ask yourself, "If this content was removed, would it disrupt the flow of the document?" If the answer is yes, then don't use it, otherwise it's ok semantically.

Comment: I think i get your point there. Thanks @zer00ne

Comment: No problem, remember semantics is not a standard it is a way to give HTML meaning and its subjective. Having said that, I try to adhere to a balance between semantics and functionality. For instance, on rare occasions I'll use a table for minor layout but use descriptive classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use a `<figure>` element to mark up a customer review. Figures are great for marking up block quotations that are meant to be self-contained within a larger body of text. Mozilla's HTML Reference has [an example of a `<figure>` and `<blockquote>` pairing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure#Quotations) on their page about the `<figure>` element.

However, if you consider each customer review to be "independently distributable or reusable" (e.g. placed on other pages or shared independently to other sites) an [`<article>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article) with an inner `<blockquote>` may be more appropriate.